# How to remove an item from a gtkMenu?

Tags: python, pygtk

I have created a gtkMenu using `gtk.Menu()`, appended a couple of items and now I want to remove some menu items. How can I do that?

Answer (score 9):

This should do the trick:

```
for i in menu.get_children():
    menu.remove(i) # check here if you want to remove this child
```

`gtk.Menu` inherits from `gtk.Container`

http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkcontainer.html

**EDIT**

```
# First remove all old timer menu items from the gtkMenu
if TimerAppIndicator.menuList:
    for i in TimerAppIndicator.menuList:
        self.menu.remove(TimerAppIndicator.menuList[j])
        j+=1 <---- 1) j isn't declared here 
                   2) you will skip items why not just self.menu.remove(i)
                      you're already iterating over the menu items


# Delete all timer menu items from the list storing them
del TimerAppIndicator.menuList[:]
j=0  <--------- shouldn't this be before j+=1?
```

Comment: Nice, thanks, this works to some extent. When I just plot `print self.menu.get_children()` then I see that the item has indeed been removed. But it does still appear in my menu. Is it possible that I still have to updated or redraw it? If yes, how?

Comment: Normally the above should work, since you didn't show us any code, I suppose that your menu is open while the item is being removed? You may want to use `queue_draw()` on the menu to force an redraw. Or you could post some of the code / elaborate where exactly the item gets removed.

Comment: Okay here we go, the bigger picture: My goal is to write an appindicator for Ubuntu where the user is able to create a timer (for a pizza or whatever), which is then supposed to appear as a menu entry and should disappear after the timer is finished. I rely on lists and a timeout for this. Here is the relevant code snippet: http://pastie.org/1320827 Line 39 is the crux I think. Removing the item from the gtk menu actually works, but it will never disappear from the appindicator!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using `destroy()` could save some RAM:

`menu.foreach(lambda child: child.destroy())`